# How to run a cron job in Heroku, with a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, sinatra, heroku

I'm writing a tiny Sinatra app, and I want to host it on [Heroku](http://heroku.com) for simplicity sake.  But, what I have is a task that scraps some sites and adds some data into my database every hour.  Currently this is just written as a ruby script that needs to be executed.  What Heroku has is a [rake based cron job](http://docs.heroku.com/cron).  Now if this was a rails app, I could easily do this, but I want to avoid the clutter for something as simple as this.

Is there a way to avoid this?  Or do I have to install rake as well with my app?

Thank you.

Eric

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a Rakefile like:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron do
 # Do something
end
```

Heroku periodically executes rake cron in your app depending on whether you have selected the "cron add-on" to be hourly or daily.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out Rufus. Rufus is your friend. Rufus will be your crontab while your app is loaded.

I did not try this stuff on Heroku but, give it a try and reply to us.

http://codex.heroku.com/past/2010/4/15/rufus_scheduler_for_my_tiny_sinatra_apps/

Why Rufus is cool? Well check this out, it's clean :)

```
$ sudo gem install rufus-scheduler

require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.cron '00 23 30 * *' do
  # Run every 30 days at 23h00m
  # ...your magic code goes here...
end
```

Comment: Looks, good.  Unfortunately Heroku doesn't support the Rufus gem yet.

Comment: autch! Maybe http://github.com/javan/whenever of maybe they dont support any of then regarding their payed "cron" add-on :/

Answer (score 1):

Looked again and looks like I jumped the gun on the question.

For applications that aren't Rails, one just has to create a `Rakefile` and put the task there.

Hope this helps other people.

Cheers!